# After enabling multi-currency, MDQ products will not add in the quote line editor

Tags: cpq

I have an issue where after enabling multi-currency and setting up three currency prices in two of our pricebooks (USD, GBP, EUR), none of our multi-demensional products will add to the quote line editor in any currency other than USD. When selecting a regular product, it adds fine in all currencies. What am I missing? I have checked to make sure all pricebooks & currencies match between the Opportunity & Quote..

Thanks,
Cole

Answer (score 0):

You have to create different MDQ per currency.

If a Product with Price Dimensions is using multiple currencies (which are stored in separate Price Books), each currency must contain it's own Price Dimension. For example: If you have 2 Price Dimensions (Dimension A & Dimension B) and are using US Dollars and Euros, you must have 4 separate Dimensions (Dimension A: USD, Dimension A: EUR, Dimension B: USD, Dimension B: EUR).